# i3-wm, Google Chrome passwords not saved

Tags: google-chrome, i3-wm

Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla
Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Google Chrome passwords do not save when I switched between different Desktop Environments (Gnome, Unity, Ubuntu, etc) and Window Managers I3, fvwm2, etc. It is saved as long I used just Gnome for instance but when I switch to I3 the same google account with all "Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click" and "Offer to save passwords I enter on the web" checked shows no passwords saved.
Google account looks OK as far on other OS (Mac, Windows) loading profile (bookmarks, theme, etc) but no stored password. And do not save passwords.
Other Internet browsers (Edge, Safari, Chromium) do the same thing therefore it looks to me that it is between DE (KDE and such) and WM (i3)

**LXDE, KDE-Plasma do not also store passwords**

[image]

Comment: please [edit] your question to indicate which version of Ubuntu yo are using as well as the browser versions.

Comment: I think he listed ALL the browsers :)

Comment: no, I did not list all, Opera, Firefox, Konqueror, Lynx ... :)